# Googlesheet formula for =HYPERLINK with autopopulation?

Tags: hyperlink, google-sheets, formula, google-apps, auto-populate

I really need a bit of help with this.

I've a sheet that autopopulates (from a submitted form).

There are currently 5 columns.

```
| Stamp         | Username      | Field | Field2 | Field3   |
|---------------|---------------|-------|--------|----------|
|06/03/2015     | Bob@whatever.c|Text12 |Blah    |INC1126363|
|06/03/2015     | Bob@whatever.c|TextABC|Blah2   |INC1128453|
|06/03/2015     | Bob@whatever.c|Text123|Blach3  |INC1126270|
```

However, I also need a 6th colum, which hyperlinks to a URL using the contents in Field3. I'm using the following formula to get the URL

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://domain.service-now.com/incident.do?sysparm_query=GOTOnumber%3D",E2,),"Check for Updates")
```

Which works, however I need the 6th colum to auto populate this. 
I have tried to use E2:E along with arrayformula (using an IF function). However, using E2:E returns the contents of the entire Field3 column, meaning the URLs aren't returning correctly. They'd come back something like:

```
https://domain.service-now.com/incident.do?sysparm_query=GOTOnumber%3DINC1126363INC1128453INC1126270
```

Anyone able to point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(E2:E), HYPERLINK("https://domain.service-now.com/incident.do?sysparm_query=GOTOnumber%3D"&E2:E, "Check for Updates"),))
```

and see if it works for you ?

Comment: Away from work atm, in tomorrow though, so will give it a proper test then. Will this reference E2, and then on the next line, E3 and E4 and so on?